# What do you call a blob of hair attached together?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's a word for it, but if there's no word for it what's the next best way to say it, is there a short phrase or something you can think of? I am thinking of a blob of hair arranged in such a way so that it's not messy and attached with something like an elastic band or something else to make sure they don't come apart.

Comment: What word would you use in your native language? Did you see if there was a translation for it?

Comment: blobs are usually liquid or liquid-like or jelly or jelly-like. A blob of wet cement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you mean a sample of hair that is cut off neatly and bound together on purpose (to be a keepsake, decoration, or lab sample, etc.), I think the word is a "hank" of hair.

"In the drawer were his baby shoes and a hank of golden hair from his first haircut."

Comment: hank of hair is not English. And **hunk of hair** is what two dogs might rip out of each other's coats when fighting.

Comment: "a piece of something such as wool or hair tied in a loose way" - definition of "hank" in MacMillan dictionary https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hank?q=hank+ ...AND...My family uses the word in this way.

Comment: It must be very regional. I have never heard it. Generally, people keep strands of hair tied with a ribbon.

Comment: Also, just because you don't know a term doesn't make it "not English"

Comment: I've heard hank, it may be a regional. In my opinion lock is more common.

Comment: Ok, so it is English. It is not usual. I have never heard it and I bet most English speakers haven't either. Yes, and tied in a loose way is not how you keep a strand of hair as a keepsake. The ribbon has to be tightly tied to keep the hair together. Yes,lock of hair. And the OED says: a circular coil or loop of anything flexible.

Comment: I agree with though about "hunk" of hair.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hank_(textile)

Answer (score 4):

There are many words for different arrangements of hair. I can't tell from the question which one you want, but these are likely options:

- If all the hair is tied in one bundle hanging down in the back, that's a **ponytail**.
- A blob of hair that is hanging together (but probably not tied) is a **lock**.

Comment: I'd also suggest **a bun**, if the hair is gathered in a rounder shape...

Comment: The question is not about hair arrangements. We do not say **blobs of hair hanging together**, really not. strands of hair, I cannot stress that enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hair that is still on someone's head, and bound together for neatness or style would usually be called a "ponytail".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponytail

Hair that has been cut off and bound together in order to be kept as a form of keepsake would be called a "lock of hair".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_of_hair

Comment: `Yes, sure, a lock of hair or a strand of hair.

Comment: A strand of hair would be a single hair, not a number of hairs bunched together.

Comment: Well, you reveal yourself there, I'm afraid. **A strand of hair is most definitely not a single hair.** And there are tons of ways to "bind" hair for neatness or style: ponytail, pigtail, bun, updo, braids, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hair is hair.'

**Hair has strands**. As in:

**She had a strand of hair hanging down in her face** as she washed the car.

- (Loose) strands of hair can be held in place with bobby or hair pins.
- Strands of hair can be held in place with barrettes or clips.

If two dogs or cats fight, they might rip out hunks of each other's hair.

The hair on your shower floor **could be called** a blob of hair (though that sort of turns the stomach).

[hair accessories](https://www.ulta.com/tools-brushes-accessories-clips-bobby-pins?N=27go)